# search in a string with multiple values Symfony 3

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, repository, symfony-3.3

I have a table that contains all the postal codes of a country.
sometimes the postal code is a single value like (01090) and sometimes it's a postal code multiple (75000-75001-75002 ...). the column type is a string.

```
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $villeCp = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:VillesFranceFree')->findBy(array('villeCodePostal' => $cp)) ;
```

when I do research on a city whose postal code is equal to 01090 it works and I had the right result but when I try to find the city with the postal code 75000 it returns nothing because in the table this city has a multiple code (75000 or 75001 or 75002)
how can I do my search if the code is multiple !

Comment: What about restructuring your database? Keep it normalized, such that you have one table for all postal codes and a relation to their city - then it's simple to access that one row where the postal code matches and find the related city

Comment: thank you for your response but I prefer to find a solution with symfony instead of changing the database because it is too long

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe a query with a like could do so.

```php
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT villeCodePostal
    FROM App\Entity\VillesFranceFree v
    WHERE v.villeCodePostal LIKE :cp'
)->setParameter('cp', '%'.$cp.'%');

$villeCp = $query->execute();
```